# Error when proxying to blog sub domain from node.js application

Tags: node.js, wordpress, .htaccess, express, proxy

I have a nodejs app hosted on heroku, on www.example.com
I then have a wordpress blog, currently on a subdomain - blog.example.com

I have a route setup in express:

(using [express-http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy))

```
var proxy = require('express-http-proxy');

app.use('/blog', proxy('blog.example.com', {
    forwardPath: function(req, res) {
        return require('url').parse(req.url).path;
    }
}));
```

This works, in the sense that I can see the blog "home page" on www.example.com/blog - it's proxying correctly and transparnelty to blog.example.com

However, if I visit any of the blog posts on there, it falls over with a 500 error

> [error] [client (ipAddressHere)] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://www.example.com/blog/

I suspect it’s something to do with my htaccess - but can’t quite figure out what?

My htaccess is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed /blog from my htaccess to make it:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

It now works 
Transparent proxying from my node app /blog to wordpress blog!