# virtual host for node app on heroku

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, heroku

I am trying to set up my blog to be displayed in a page instead of a subdomain. So if a post is post-1, I want the following:

```
blog.mydomain.com/post-1 --> mydomain.com/blog/post-1
```

The problem is that my app is a node app on Heroku and my blog is a wordpress. I looked at modifying the **htaccess** but if I am not mistaken, htaccess is only for PHP. 
Could somebody point me in the right direction ?

Comment: It seems to me you want to serve your blog from your top level domain instead of the subdomain.

Comment: I can't do that. My app is on my top level domain. I just want the blog to be accessible from mydomain.com/blog instead of the subdomain

Comment: This post explains how to do it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29628351/error-when-proxying-to-blog-sub-domain-from-node-js-application

Comment: @CyrilGaillard - have you resolved this? because I have same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your own domain name with herkoku by following the steps listed here

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: I am using it already to have my app on mydomain.com. I need to set up mydomain/blog, which I don't think you can do with custom domain

Comment: Why don't you just prefix your routes with /blog??